# ¿Cómo puedo enviar una cadena a una variable mysql cuando no se carga una imagen?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mvc

Este es un modal para registrar un usuario. El código funciona bien cuando se carga y envía una imagen, sin embargo cuando se desea registrar los datos de un nuevo usuario sin cargar una imagen salta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto, en caso de que no se suba ningún archivo quisiera enviar a la base de datos solo la siguiente cadena: *"vistas/img/productos/default/anonymous.png"*. Es decir, no hay necesidad que en el controlador se obtenga el tamaño de la imagen y tampoco crear un directorio para almacenar eso.

**Este es el código del controlador:**

```
static public function ctrCrearUsuario(){

        if(isset($_POST["nuevoUsuario"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoNombre"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoUsuario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoPassword"])){

                $ruta = "vistas/img/productos/default/anonymous.png";

                if(isset($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"])){
                    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);
                    $nuevoAncho = 500;
                    $nuevoAlto = 500;

                    /* Creacion del directorio para guardar imagen*/

                    $directorio = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"];
                    mkdir($directorio, 0755);

                    /* Guardar imagen en el directorio*/

                    if($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"){                   
                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);
                        $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".jpg";
                        $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);                    
                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);
                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);
                        imagejpeg($destino, $ruta);

                    }

                    /* Guardar imagen */
                    if($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["type"] == "image/png"){
                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);
                        $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".png";
                        $origen = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);                     
                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);
                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);
                        imagepng($destino, $ruta);
                    }

                }

                $tabla = "usuarios";
                $encriptar = crypt($_POST["nuevoPassword"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
                $datos = array("nombre" => $_POST["nuevoNombre"],
                               "usuario" => $_POST["nuevoUsuario"],
                               "password" => $encriptar,
                               "perfil" => $_POST["nuevoPerfil"],
                               "foto"=>$ruta);

                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos);

                if($respuesta == "ok"){
                    echo '<script>
                    swal({

                        type: "success",
                        title: "¡El usuario ha sido guardado correctamente!",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"

                    }).then(function(result){

                        if(result.value){
                        
                            window.location = "usuarios";

                        }

                    });     
                    </script>';
                }   


            }else{
                echo '<script>
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        title: "¡El usuario no puede ir vacío o llevar caracteres especiales!",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"

                    }).then(function(result){

                        if(result.value){
                        
                            window.location = "usuarios";

                        }

                    });
                
                </script>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No deberías comprobar primero que se haya mandado algo? Haciendo 7n simple if `if $_FILES['img']{ ->hace algo} else{guarda img defult}`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la pista, ya pude resolver el problema :)

Comment: seria bueno que compartas la forma en que solucionaste tu problema, puedes responder a tu propia pregunta o aceptar la respuesta que tienes (solo si resolvió tu problema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estas validando que el valor de la imagen sea un valor no vacío ya que se puede presentar el caso. Esto sucede porque el valor por defecto de un input cuando un archivo no es seleccionado, según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) es `""`. Y si te das cuenta el error salta en `getImageSize()` ya que la ruta entonces sería `""`.

Al hacer la validación con [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) no tomas en cuenta el caso en el que la cadena es vacía puesto que esa no es la finalidad de `isset()` ya que solo valida que la variable esté definida y no sea `null`. Para hacer más robusta la validación pudes usar [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) para validar que la cadena no sea una cadena vacía y que tu variable `$ruta` no sufra cambios indebidos al entrar a ese if.

```php
static public function ctrCrearUsuario(){

        if(isset($_POST["nuevoUsuario"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoNombre"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoUsuario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoPassword"])){

                $ruta = "vistas/img/productos/default/anonymous.png";

                if(isset($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]) && !empty($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"])){
                    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);
                    $nuevoAncho = 500;
                    $nuevoAlto = 500;

                    /* Creacion del directorio para guardar imagen*/

                    $directorio = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"];
                    mkdir($directorio, 0755);

                    /* Guardar imagen en el directorio*/

                    if($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"){                   
                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);
                        $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".jpg";
                        $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);                    
                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);
                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);
                        imagejpeg($destino, $ruta);

                    }

                    /* Guardar imagen */
                    if($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["type"] == "image/png"){
                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);
                        $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".png";
                        $origen = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);                     
                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);
                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);
                        imagepng($destino, $ruta);
                    }

                }

                $tabla = "usuarios";
                $encriptar = crypt($_POST["nuevoPassword"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
                $datos = array("nombre" => $_POST["nuevoNombre"],
                               "usuario" => $_POST["nuevoUsuario"],
                               "password" => $encriptar,
                               "perfil" => $_POST["nuevoPerfil"],
                               "foto"=>$ruta);

                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos);

                if($respuesta == "ok"){
                    echo '<script>
                    swal({

                        type: "success",
                        title: "¡El usuario ha sido guardado correctamente!",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"

                    }).then(function(result){

                        if(result.value){
                        
                            window.location = "usuarios";

                        }

                    });     
                    </script>';
                }   


            }else{
                echo '<script>
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        title: "¡El usuario no puede ir vacío o llevar caracteres especiales!",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"

                    }).then(function(result){

                        if(result.value){
                        
                            window.location = "usuarios";

                        }

                    });
                
                </script>';
            }
        }
    }
```